# .Net Bootstrap Col Md all go to center of page in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, .net, bootstrap-4

I have this page :

//Scripts

```
 <link href="../Scripts/Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
```

//html

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                         <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_tb_Registo" data-error="wrong" data-success="right" >Tipo Registo</asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tb_registo" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2" id="div_poid" runat="server">
                <div class="form-group">
                         <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_poid" data-error="wrong" data-success="right" >PO Id</asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tb_poid" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2" id="div_erroid" runat="server">
                <div class="form-group">
                         <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_erroid" data-error="wrong" data-success="right" >Erro Id</asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tb_erroid" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2" id="div_nuv" runat="server">
                <div class="form-group">
                         <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_nuv" data-error="wrong" data-success="right" >NUV</asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tb_nuv" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2" id="div_itemvendaid" runat="server">
                <div class="form-group">
                         <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_itemvendaid" data-error="wrong" data-success="right" >Item Venda Id</asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tb_itemvendaid" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This HTML code should look aligned and next to eachother but they all do a Waterfall effect and align at the center in Internet Explorer and only at Internet Explorer 11.
Can anyone explain me why ?

Comment: Which version of Internet Explorer? What OS?

Comment: I am using IE11

Comment: Why is this tagged Bootstrap 4? The code is using Bootstrap 3.